# Clicking button to add its text to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I have this code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdNdXd which lets me pick wheels, tiers etc. The thing I want to do is when I get to the last div, where the description of an items is displayed, I have a button and I want to make it when that button is clicked its text is added in the bellow div called Cart, this works as a shoping cart. If you pick Farovi then Original and then Devil eyes you can see that you get text with product name, its code and price, the second line has a button, so I want when I press that button that item gets added to the cart in the div bellow. Is this possible and how can I delte one of products from shopping cart if I want.
Tried a few diferent codes but could not to get it working, last one I tried is append function but could not get it working. This bellow is just example of append function, I did not use this one in my code

```
$( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:
Form your HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="item" id="link1">Felge</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="item" id="link2">Gume</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="item" id="link3">Branici</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="item" id="link4">Farovi</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="cart"></div>
```

And JavaScript like this:

```
function addToCart(item) {
    var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
    $("#cart").append("<p><a class='cartitem' href='#'   onclick='removeFromCart(this)'>" + item.innerHTML + "</a></p>");

    $('.cartitem').click(function (e) {
        $(e.target).remove();
    });
}

function removeFromCart(ele) {
    $("#cart").remove(ele);
}
$(function () {
    $('.item').click(function () {
        addToCart(this);
    });
});
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/8npoj1nq/

Comment: Thank you for help. I did as you suggested but I changed last div with product info not the first div. Thank you:)